# Multitasking definition

Tags: multitasking

I'm studying for CISSP exam and I've found a strange definition of multitasking

> In computing, multitasking means handling two or more task simultaneously. In the past, most system did not truly multitask because they relied on the operative system to simulate multitasking by carefully structuring the sequence of commands sent to the CPU for execution. ... A single-core multi-tasking system is able to juggle more than one task or process at any given time.

A single core cannot be multitasking because it cannot process more than one task at given time...it usually performs a context-switching to simulate multitasking. It is more or less what was done by operative systems in the past (and now). So I don't unterstand the statemens above. Am I wrong?

Comment: They are a description of preemptive and non-preemptive multitasking...They aren't related to the question above

Comment: "*In computing, multitasking means handling two or more task simultaneously*" -- With a single-core CPU, the tasks are executed *concurrently*, rather than *simultaneously*.   Back in the day when there were only single-core CPUs, the difference between *concurrent* and  *simultaneous* was always stressed in OS classes & textbooks.  Linux, a multitasking kernel & operating system. can run on single-core and multi-core CPUs.

Comment: I agree with you: a single core CPU cannot execute two or more task simultaneously. Hence the statement **A single-core multi-tasking system is able to juggle more than one task or process at any given time** is wrong. Do you agree?

Comment: I do not agree.  The use of "*juggle*" seems to be a substitute word to avoid explaining how *concurrent* execution would be performed.   It's really bad wording, but not false.  My objection to that text is the use of "*in the past*".  In the present, there are still many single-core systems running multitasking OSes!  PCs, tablets, and smart phones are not all the computers in the world.

Comment: Ok, understood. Let's try to recap: a multi-tasking system can be done only with a multi-core system. A single-core system can only "simulate" (I'm using the same word used in the sentence) a multi-tasking. "Juggle" doesn't mean it is a real "single core multi tasking system". Am I right?

Comment: No, if if you have a multi-core CPU, it will also have to "*juggle*" tasks (or simulate multitasking) as you increase the number of tasks.  It's marketing that claims that multi-core is the real solution.  See my answer below.

Comment: Technically a CPU with hyperthreading is able to achieve multitasking *within the CPU core*. It appears to an operating system as two CPUs, and the architectural stuff around the CPU is distict and separate, but the CPU resources that perform actual tasks such as addition/multiplication and so on may be shared resulting in a chain of instructions from one process being somewhat intermingled with that of another. In theory that could be considered "multitasking" with the hardware handling multiple tasks at once.

Comment: I don't agree: multitasking means simultaneously execution. In hyperthreading this cannot be achieved because the ALU is only one. You could improve the pipeline using the additional resources (registers), however the ALU (the execution logic) is always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single-core CPU, the tasks can only be executed *concurrently*, rather than *simultaneously*. Back in the day when there were only single-core CPUs, the difference between *concurrent* and *simultaneous* was always stressed in OS classes & textbooks.

The techniques to achieve *concurrent* execution, such as context switching and scheduling methods (e.g. priority vs round-robin, preemptive vs cooperative) are still very relevant in an age of multi-core CPUs simply because the operating system is not assured of having an available core for every task it needs to execute.
The OS needs to assume the number of cores (or execution units) will be less than the number of tasks that need to be executed.

Hence all the concepts developed to perform *concurrent* execution of tasks are still employed in modern operating systems while performing a limited number of *simultaneous* executions of tasks.

Comment: I think hyperthreading is something that could be added here. In hyperthreading there is only one core set of hardware doing actual calculations, but that "core" section of the CPU is shared across two hardware threads. There are two concurrent streams of independent instructions being fed into one execution core and could be considered a form of simultaneous multitasking.

Comment: IMO the focus on multi-cores and parallelism is overblown, and is marketing hype. The actual benefits depend on the type of work you perform on a computer (e.g. tasks that are not 100% compute bound). When a task needs to perform I/O (e.g. read a file) that task's request is queued behind other pending filesystem requests, and the task is suspended. The advantages of simultaneous execution in the CPU for that task are now rendered irrelevant while it waits for I/O to complete.

Answer (score 1):

**Context-switching** is a heavy operation that involves saving all the
registers of the current task and loading instead those of another task.

**Multitasking** is the ability of a computer to run more than
one program or task at the same time.
Multitasking contrasts with single-tasking, where one process
must entirely finish before another can begin.
Context-switching is the tool used for enabling multitasking.

MS-DOS is an example for a single-tasking environment.
Windows 3.1 and later are multi-tasking environments.

Comment: Context-switching is only an example...What seems wrong to me is the statement **A single-core multi-tasking system is able to juggle more than one task or process at any given time.** because you need a multicore system for real multi tasking.

Comment: I rewrote my answer - is it clearer now?

Comment: Moreover the statement **In the past, most system did not truly multitask because they relied on the operative system to simulate multitasking by carefully structuring the sequence of commands sent to the CPU for execution.** is a mess because the difference between new and old operative systems is how multitasking is performed...a multitasking on a single core is always "simulated"

Comment: My question is different...please read my comments

Comment: It depends what you call "old". Newer CPUs can now execute several tasks in parallel, by having much more registers than allocated to each user, and by mapping these to the user's visible registers. The CPU unit then executes dumb atomic operations like "R1+R2=>R3" without context-switching.

Comment: Newer CPUs have also more ALU because they are multi-core. On a single core system (which as only one arithmetic-logic unit) a multi-tasking mechanism can only be "simulated". This is in contrast with the statement in bold above

Comment: No, nowadays a core has multiple units, even of the same kind, plus sophisticated logic that makes it all work. Cores haven't had a single unit, and this since something like a decade now.

Comment: Single core means one physical core, hence one physical ALU.  If you're talking about virtual/logical cores there is only one single ALU plus more logic able to perform some sort of parallelism in the pipeline.  However the ALU can execute only one instruction per time so technically speaking it cannot perform a real multitasking alone.

Comment: Even if you have a multi-core CPU, context switches still occur.

Comment: That's long past. See [Apple M1](https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm.html) with 6 integer units, 4 load/store and 4 floating-point. Time has passed and CPUs have evolved beyond these concepts.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0):

Technically multitasking is different from multiprocessing.

Where I'd say that multiprocessing is prone to be hardware dependent to a higher degree; allowing true concurrent execution of (e.g.) cpu code: i.e. **that** is what you're discussing elsewhere above/below of here.

To have true gain from several cpu-cores for a single software project requires the software to be built with multiprocessing in mind (e.g Hugin-MP, for multi-image panorama stitching).

**Opinion based on experience;**
"Windows 3.1" uses/used cooperative multitasking, each task/program had to "let go" of the CPU (i.e. the task would block all other software from getting anywhere until it did).
This was VERY evident in how Windows 3 "multitasked".

The Amiga computer used "preemptive multitasking" on it's (pre multicore, WITH context switches) M68K and the experience was vastly different from Windows(3!).
Simple tasks as formatting one or even a few disks was nicely done,
while you spent time on other things;
e.g. burning a CD, playing music, editing a file, browsing the web and chatting; all at once.

This was NOT possible when using Windows; and that remained so - with minuscule improvements only - until "7" or so.
Burning a CD alone required full availability to the CPU, or it failed with "buffer underrun" (the write buffer could not be filled quick enough).

*Note also: The "retro" Amiga world exists and is thriving - even though slowly, even hardware-wise (new PCBS!). I'm not sure that is the case w.r.t Windows 3.*